# How to set images in a viewPager slider

Tags: java, android

I have an idea on how to go about this but will require some coding expertise on the issue.

I currently have a image picker set up where the user can select multiple picutres. I alos have a slider developer using pageViewer. Now the problem with pageViewer is that it requires images to already be stored before you run the app so that it can display those images in the slider.

So this is the idea I have which I hope can be done.

- User selects their images from their photos
- After user selection, the images are stored in the internal storage and each image will have a file name of 'imageSelected_...'. The ... is a number so '`imageSelected_1`', '`imageSelected_2`', '`imageSelect_3`' etc. That is how we associate these imagers
- Within our pageVieweradapater we store the name of these files our viewPager code so that the slider will display those images.

That's how I am thinking of selecting images and getting them displayed in the slider. The help I require is implementation.

Below is the code for selecting multiple images:

PhotosActivity:

```
public void openGallery() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_MULTIPLE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        try {
            // When an Image is picked
            if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                    && null != data) {
                // Get the Image from data

                String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
                imagesEncodedList = new ArrayList<String>();
                if(data.getData()!=null){

                    Uri mImageUri=data.getData();

                    // Get the cursor
                    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(mImageUri,
                            filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                    // Move to first row
                    cursor.moveToFirst();

                    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                    imageEncoded  = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                    cursor.close();

                    imageDisplay.setImageURI(mImageUri);

                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "You haven't picked Image",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

Below is the viewPagerAdapter and calling on it from PhotoActivites for the imageslider. It takes pictures from the drawable folder for now but want it to match with my previous bullets points.

photosViewPagerAdapter:

```
public class PhotosViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private Integer [] images = {R.drawable.question, R.drawable.love_heart, R.drawable.love_heart_dark};

    public PhotosViewPagerAdapter(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return images.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view,  Object object) {
        return view == object;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position){
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_photos, null);
        ImageView imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.image_content);
        imageView.setImageResource(images[position]);

        ViewPager vp  = (ViewPager) container;
        vp.addView(view, 0);
        return view;

    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object){
        ViewPager vp  = (ViewPager) container;
        View view = (View) object;
        vp.removeView(view);
    }
```

PhotosActivity:

```
ViewPager photosSlider;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

PhotosViewPagerAdapter photosViewPagerAdapter = new PhotosViewPagerAdapter(PhotosActivity.this);
        photosSlider.setAdapter(photosViewPagerAdapter);
```